# file upload not working in react native with multipart form data api nodejs

Tags: node.js, react-native, multer

I am trying to upload image file with react native, by using nodejs multipart api, but the file is not getting sent from the FE. If I console req.files its undefined at server side. Here is my react native code:

```
       var options = {
           title: 'Select Image',
           storageOptions: {
               skipBackup: true,
               path: 'images'
           }
       };
       ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
           console.log('Response = ', response);
           if (response.didCancel) {
               console.log('User cancelled image picker');
           } else if (response.error) {
               console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
           } else if (response.customButton) {
               console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
           } else {
               console.log('User selected a file form camera or gallery', response);
               const data = new FormData();
               data.append('name', 'avatar');
               data.append('file', {
                   uri: response.uri,
                   type: response.type,
                   name: response.fileName
               });
               const config = {
                   method: 'POST',
                   headers: {
                       'Accept': 'application/json',
                       'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                   },
                   body: data,
               };
               fetch("http://myapi.com/api/v1/user", config)
                   .then((checkStatusAndGetJSONResponse) => {
                       console.log(checkStatusAndGetJSONResponse);
                   }).catch((err) => { console.log(err) });
           }
       }
       )
```

and Nodejs code:

```
const storage = multer.memoryStorage({
    destination:(req, file, callback) => {
        callback(null, '')
    }
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage }).array('file');
    upload(req,res,(err) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log('ERROR: ',err);
            return res.end("Error uploading file.");
        }else{
            console.log('REQUEST: ',req.files);
        }
    });
```

I am not able to upload image with some user data, please let me know what am doing wrong here
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

as you are sending form data in body, it will only hold that form data.

if you want to send form data plus some other data, then try to append form data in another object and then append other data in same object with key value pair.

I have created user register form in which I have some input fields and profile upload.
For upload I have used "**ngx-file-drop**".

like:-

```
const body = {};
body['formData'] = formValues;
body['fileData'] = this.fileDataArray;
```

In this the ts code is like below.

```
dropped(files: NgxFileDropEntry[]) {
    this.fileError = false;
    this.files = [];
    this.files = files;
    for (const droppedFile of files) {
      // Is it a file?
      if (droppedFile.fileEntry.isFile && this.isFileAllowed(droppedFile.fileEntry.name)) {
        this.filesArray.push(droppedFile);
        const fileEntry = droppedFile.fileEntry as FileSystemFileEntry;
         const formData: FormData = new FormData();
        fileEntry.file((file: File) => {
          
        });
        fileEntry.file((file: File) => {
          this.dropFilePath.push(droppedFile.relativePath);
          // append form data
          formData.append('upload', file, droppedFile.relativePath);
          this.dropFile.push(file);
          this.dropFileFlag = true;
        });
      } else {
        // It was a directory (empty directories are added, otherwise only files)
        const fileEntry = droppedFile.fileEntry as FileSystemDirectoryEntry;
        this.dropFilePath = [];
        this.dropFile = [];
        this.files = [];

        this.toaster.error('only this file are allowed : [".jpg", ".jpeg",".gif",".png"]', 'Error', {
          positionClass: 'toast-top-full-width',
        });
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

and html code is.

```
<ngx-file-drop [disabled]="isPreview ? true : null" dropZoneLabel="Drop files here" (onFileDrop)="dropped($event)" (onFileOver)="fileOver($event)"(onFileLeave)="fileLeave($event)">
<ng-template ngx-file-drop-content-tmp let-openFileSelector="openFileSelector">
    <span [attr.disabled]="isPreview ? true : null" class="btn">Drop files here or</span>
       <span [attr.disabled]="isPreview ? true : null" (click)="openFileSelector()" class="btn btn-link">click to upload</span>
</ng-template>
</ngx-file-drop>
```

and on form submit you can do like this.

```
onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;

    if (this.form.invalid || (this.submitted && this.fileError)) {
      this.toaster.error('Invalid form data..!!', 'ERROR');
      return;
    }
    const formData = this.form.value;
    this.fileDataArray.push(formData.getAll('upload'));
    console.log('this.fileDataArray-------->', this.fileDataArray);
    const body = {};
    body['formData'] = formData;
    body['fileData'] = this.fileDataArray;
    console.log('body------>', body);
    // call below your api function
   }
```

Comment: I think its angular code, but am want for react-native @nilesh-solanki

Comment: @VishalRana yeah, its angular, I have provided an idea that you can send formdata plus user other data in a common object with different kev value pair.

Comment: my task is to upload the file in react-native, with angular it's very easy to do.

Comment: have you checked the data append name you are sending from client side and the data you are fetching at server are same.

Comment: just check this link if it help's you.
<https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/how-to-upload-images-in-a-react-native-app-4cca03ded855>

Comment: Thank for your efforts, I tried all these. The API is working perfectly with postman, but its not working with react-native